# Matrix clause or infinitival clause?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, grammatical-roles, infinitive-constructions, for-to-complementizers, constituents

What is the function of “the doctor” in the following sentences? Is it a constituent of the matrix clause or of the infinitival clause?

1. I wanted the doctor to examine my daughter.
2. I persuaded the doctor to examine my daughter.
3. I expected the doctor to examine my daughter.
4. I told the doctor to examine my daughter.
5. I would hate for the doctor to examine my daughter.

Comment: In (2) and (4), _the doctor_ functions as the indirect object of the matrix verb, and also as the subject of the infinitive; _persuade_ and _tell_ are B-Equi predicates. In (1), (3), and (5), however, _the doctor_ does not originate in the matrix clause; rather, in (1) and (3) it's a B-Raised subject of the infinitive; _want_ and _expect_  govern [Raising, not Equi](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf). In (5), _the doctor_ is the unraised subject of the infinitive, marked as such by the undeleted _for_ complementizer.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for such a succinct yet clear answer. Might I trouble you to please put it in the answer box?

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> In (2) and (4), *the doctor* functions as the indirect object of the matrix verb, and also as the subject of the infinitive; *persuade* and *tell* are B-Equi predicates.
>
> In (1), (3), and (5), however, *the doctor* does not originate in the matrix clause; rather, in (1) and (3) it's a B-Raised subject of the infinitive; *want* and *expect*  govern [Raising, not Equi](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).
>
> In (5), *the doctor* is the unraised subject of the infinitive, marked as such by the undeleted *for* complementizer.